# docpad+mongodb Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]

Tags: mongodb, docpad

```
$ docpad run
warning: Skipped the unsupported plugin: mongoose-validate due to engine
info: Welcome to DocPad v6.35.0
info: Plugins: cleanurls, coffeescript, eco, livereload, marked, partials, stylus, text
info: Environment: development
info: DocPad listening to http://localhost:3001/ on directory /home/dennis/github/example.com/out
info: LiveReload listening to new socket on channel /docpad-livereload with log level 1
Currently on writeFiles at 127/127 100% =================================================Warning: Task "min concat cssmin" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
info: Generating...
error: An error occured: 
Error: failed to connect to [undefined:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/dennis/github/example.com/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:604:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:108:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/dennis/github/example.com/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:139:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:100:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/dennis/github/example.com/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:476:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:97:17)
    at net.js:874:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)
```

MongoDB is running. I also tried removing MongoDB's lock file, running repair, and restarting MongoDB but no luck. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: undefined:27017 should instead be hostname:27017 - are you specifying the hostname for your mongodb?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I'm not explicitly specifying anything for mongo/mongodb, should I be? Can you give an example?

Comment: what host is mongod running on?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky localhost.

Comment: @laggingreflex no, unfortunately not.